# TFDQuery.SQL - change SQL statement via TEdit

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to access my SQL Query via TEdit - simply to change the query during runtime for testing.

So I just build a simple TEdit field. I'm struggling to understand the way to access the saved string in FDQuery.SQL - it is saved like an array?

Maybe somebody can give me a hint on how to edit the Query via TEdit.

```
TEdit.Text := FDQuery1.SQL.Strings['Simply a text string?'];
```

Comment: `FDQuery.SQL.Text := '...';`

Comment: [`TFDQuery.SQL`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomQuery.SQL) can hold multiple lines of text, so maybe you'd like to use `TMemo` component instead like this: `Memo1.Lines := FDQuery1.SQL`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments - I missed FDQuery.SQL.Text...

so for me

```
 EditQuery.Text := FDQuery1.SQL.Text;
```

was the simple solution.